# How to forward port with UPnP?

Tags: networking, nat, upnp

I want to forward port at work, but when i run

```
upnpc -a 192.168.8.80 45444 45444 TCP
```

I get an error

```
List of UPNP devices found on the network :
 desc: http://192.168.15.34:5000/ssdp/desc-DSM-eth0.xml
 st: upnp:rootdevice

UPnP device found. Is it an IGD ? : http://192.168.15.34:5000/
Trying to continue anyway
Local LAN ip address : 192.168.8.80
GetExternalIPAddress failed.
GetSpecificPortMappingEntry() failed with code -1 (Miniupnpc Unknown Error)
```

Comment: Looks like UPnP is disabled and one possible solution is to use service like ngrok.com